# How to destroy the single colliding object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hope you're well. I've been trying to make it so when the bullet collides with the enemy, the enemy dies using the `Destory(gameObject);` function.

Yet, when it destroys the `gameObject`, this prevents the enemies from spawning as the spawner cannot find the `gameObject`.

So, I'd need to make it so `Destory(gameObject);` only destroys a single enemy bullet hits, not the full `gameObject`.

Comment: if you want to reuse the gameObject, instead of destroying, try to disabling it.

Comment: @Lotan thanks for the reply, I just tried gameObject.SetActive(false); and it didn't work. Is there another method to disable it?

Comment: when you say "it didn't work" you mean that the gameObject is still visible? attach a picture of your hierarchy (with your bullets, enemies and stuff) please

Comment: Please add your code and explain in more detail how your design works

Answer (score -1):

your mistake is you are destroying the referenced object, and your other script wants to call it.

do not use a scene object as reference object. make it a prefab, and than drag that prefab on object with script. it will solve your problem.